# How to determine which R package contains a function?

Tags: r

In Python one can write

```
import numpy as np
print np.random.randn(10)
```

to make clear that the function random.randn comes from numpy.

When I download an R code from the web, such as the one below, I'd like to know which functions are imported from each library. Is there a way to do this other than commenting out each "library" statement and seeing where the code breaks?

```
library(pracma)
library(quantmod)
library(fractaldim)

calculate_EI <- function(fxdata){

colnames(fxdata) <- c("data")

approx_entropy_for_symbol <- approx_entropy(fxdata, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(fxdata), elag = 1)
random_dist <- rnorm(length(fxdata))
approx_entropy_threshold <- approx_entropy(random_dist, edim = 2, r= 0.2*sd(random_dist), elag = 1) 

fractal_dimension_for_symbol <- fd.estimate(as.data.frame(fxdata$data)$data)$fd
hurst_exponent_for_symbol <- hurstexp(as.data.frame(fxdata$data)$data, d = 50)$Hal

EI$value <- ((approx_entropy_for_symbol-approx_entropy_threshold)/approx_entropy_threshold)^2
EI$approx_entropy_contribution <- ((approx_entropy_for_symbol-approx_entropy_threshold)/approx_entropy_threshold)^2
EI$value <- EI$value + ((fractal_dimension_for_symbol-1.5))^2
EI$fractal_dimension_contribution <- ((fractal_dimension_for_symbol-1.5))^2
EI$value <- EI$value + ((hurst_exponent_for_symbol-0.5))^2
EI$hurst_exponent_contribution <- ((hurst_exponent_for_symbol-0.5))^2
EI$value <- sqrt(EI$value)

return(EI)
}

#sample case
getSymbols("EUR/USD",src="oanda") 
fxdata <- EURUSD
EI <- calculate_EI(fxdata)
EI
```

Comment: In the documentation of the function is the name of the package, from where the function is, e.g. `help()` is from the package {utils}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some useful functions for finding objects like `getAnywhere` and the package `sos` if you don't have the packages on your search path.  Also, one could use the parsing data to try and do it programmatically, but it won't get everything, like in cases where functions are passed as strings or other weird cases.  Anyway, here is a quick example if you had that code stored in "test.R" (as @javK noted, the packages would need to be loaded so getAnywhere can find them in this example).

```
src <- parse(file="test.R", keep.source = TRUE)
tokens <- getParseData(src)
funs <- tokens[tokens$token == "SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL",]
res <- lapply(funs$text, function(x) getAnywhere(x)$where)

## Return a list of the functions along with the environment they in
## truncated...
setNames(res, funs$text)
# ...
# $c
# [1] "package:base"   "namespace:base"
# $approx_entropy
# [1] "package:pracma"   "namespace:pracma"
# $sd
# [1] "package:stats"   "namespace:stats"
# $rnorm
# [1] "package:stats"   "namespace:stats"
# ...
```

Comment: Note that, appropriate package should be loaded first for this to work. Otherwise it will not find them.

Comment: Thanks, answer accepted. I may modify the script so that it does not show functions that come from packages:base or package:stats.